# Error NPE then setup adapter of the listview

Tags: android, listview, runtime-error, listadapter

```
public class Tab1 extends Activity {

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab1);

    Document doc = MainActivity.parser.getDomElement(MainActivity.xml);
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("tab1");

    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(MainActivity.KEY_ID,
                MainActivity.parser.getValue(e, MainActivity.KEY_ID));
        ...

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        itemList.add(map);
    }

    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, itemList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);  <<<<<< ERROR <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
}
```

-

```
Error - java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity        
ComponentInfo{com.example.tabhost/com.example.tabhost.Tab1}: java.lang.NullPointerException

E/AndroidRuntime(2822): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

LazyAdapter.java

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position) ; 
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title

        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_TITLE));

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post the rest of your logcat and explain the problem. But looks like something is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't setting the list variable anywhere.  You need to do  `list = (ListView)findViewById(id.of.your.lisview);`